# JavaScript not working in IE8 / IE7 but fine in every other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am really new to javaScript so please bear with me. The code I have used is a mish mash of all sorts.

Basically what the script does is calculates a price based on how many pallets they choose and where they are shipping to and from and which zone it is (Four Zones per country)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/f3wz6/)**

All this is working fine but when I comes to IE8 the script doesn't work and I cannot figure out why.

I do see an error when I load the console on IE8. The error is:

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.
Line 437 character 7
```

which is this line of code

```
var fromCountry = document.querySelector('input[name="from_country"]:checked').value;
```

A working demo is located here - http://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/f3wz6/

I think some of it is Pure JavaScript and some of it is jQuery. Does this matter? Could this be a problem?

Any help on making this code function better would be a great help.

Comment: Have you tried: `$('input[name="from_country"]:checked').val()` ???

Comment: querySelector isn't available in IE7 http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: The jQuery version you're using is IE8 compatible so it may have to do with the vanilla JS.  Try rewriting that bit in jQuery (simple) and see if that changes anything.  Some of the vanilla JS functions you are relying in are likely not supported in ancient IE.

Comment: You can't always trust IE line numbers.

Comment: Let me try and re-write the small JS function in jQuery and see what happens.

Comment: Seems like the error is caused by `:checked` portion of the selector

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, `querySelector` isn't available in IE7. Since you're using jQuery, you should re-write it like:

```
  $('input[name="from_country"]:checked').val()
```

Behind the scenes, jQuery does a check to see if the browser supports the efficient `querySelector` method, and if it does, it uses it. Otherwise, it will fall back to using the broadly compatible Sizzle selector engine.